# Often I don't, I often don't

Tags: grammar

As the sentences 1 and 2 unlike 3 and 4 are unidiomatic and  without additional  information they don't work as standalone sentences, would they work if I used them in the following way with some additional information?

1."Often, I don't read when I am in a bad mood.

2. "I often don't read when I am in a bad mood.

1."Often, I don't read."
2. "I often don't read."
3. "I don't read often."
4.I don't often read.

Comment: Both 1 and 2 seem to me unnatural ways to express the idea. I think it would be more natural to say something like "When I'm in a bad mood, I don't usually feel like reading".

Comment: @KateBunting is this word order  unnatural when talking about habits only? Because as we discussed earlier these are correct "I often don't see seagulls" and "Often, I don't see seagulls" mean there are occasions when I don't see them.

Comment: I didn't say they were 'correct'; I said they were less natural than "I don't often see seagulls", but if someone _did_ say it  that way round, it would mean 'there are man y occasions when I don't'.

Comment: @KateBunting, then these are also less natural and have the  meaning =there are occasions when I don't)  "Often, I don't read the newspaper, I often don't read the newspaper,  less natural than I don't often read the newspaper. And  I often don't feel hungry and Often, I don't feel hungry less natural than I don't often feel hungry and mean there are occasions when I don't feel hungry. Right?

Comment: Please re-read my comments on your earlier question. These sentences with _often_ at or near the beginning require context and/or additional information such as 'Often _at mealtimes_ I don't feel hungry'.